# Apache Ignite 3 support for SQL DECIMAL type

Tags: ignite

Does Apache Ignite 3 support SQL DECIMAL column types, and if so, how does one go about inserting a record using JDBC?  I seem to be unable to insert a record into a cache in Ignite 3 if the column is defined to have SQL type DECIMAL.

Running the following test throws an Exception at executeUpdate() trying to insert the record:

```
public class DecimalTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10801/")) {
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                stmt.executeUpdate(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST (" +
                            "KEY_COL INT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                            "TEST_COL DECIMAL)"
                );
            }

            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO TEST (KEY_COL, TEST_COL) values (?,?)")) {
                stmt.setInt(1, 1);
                stmt.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal("123"));
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following error is produced:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exception while executing query [query=INSERT INTO TEST (KEY_COL, TEST_COL) values (?,?)]. Error message:IGN-CMN-65535 TraceId:e5ca6a42-e193-4a9c-98bc-dbc0881ac31a For conversion to decimal, ConverterUtils#convertToDecimal method should be used instead.
```

Debugging into the Ignite 3 code itself, this is being thrown deep down in ConverterUtils#convert() while its parsing the query expression:

```
public static Expression convert(Expression operand, Type fromType, Type toType) {

 // ...
     
 if (toType == BigDecimal.class) {
   throw new AssertionError("For conversion to decimal, ConverterUtils#convertToDecimal method should be used instead.");
 }

 // ...

}
```

This almost looks like it can't accept a BigDecimal type at all.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using the beta version of Apache Ignite 3. As for now, the test should work on main git branch.
The issue has been fixed under [IGNITE-18479](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-18479) for Apache Ignite 3 and [IGNITE-16711](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16711) for Apache Ignite 2.